# Trying to pull in a folder inside /opt/lampp/htdocs: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: linux, git, github

Im trying to pull my github project in my folder which is inside in htdocs. It doesnt matter what i do, it always throw the same error and i cant clone or pull from a remote repository.

The error i got is this:

"git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
"

i've tried to make a new ssh key with rsa and added with the following command:
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` 
Also, added it to my ssh keys in github.
Addtionaly, i used the next command:
`ssh -T git@github.com` 
to check if im using the correct keys.

The result of the last command above was:
"Hi alfito69420! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Finally, i tried to clone via http and the result was the same, i got the same error "Permission denied (publickey)...".

However, it still throwing the same error and i dont know what else can it be.

Finally, i have to add that if a make pull from other folder like someone in /Desktop theres no problem to pull.

**UPDATE**

After searching on internet what can i do found that just changing the privileges of the entire directory with `chmod` will solve my problem. I know that this is an insecure method, but in my case is just for a school project so it will for a while. Also, making the sshkey from root user and adding it to my ssh keys in github as the answer below solved the problem.

Comment: "*Addtionaly, i used the next command: `ssh -T git@github.com` to check if im using the correct keys.*" What was the result? "*Finally, i tried to clone via http and the same.*" What does it mean "the same"? Please show the text of error message(s) if there were any. What command do you use to pull? Do you use `sudo`?

Comment: @phd hi, sorry for my late reply. Thank you for telling me about my errors in my redaction. Ive corrected what you pointed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Finally, I tried to clone via HTTPS and the same

That means... your SSH key, even if it is working as intended with ssh -Tv git@github.com, was not used. At all.

Try instead to check:

- the URL used in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` (`cd /opt/lampp/htdocs` + `git remote -v`)
- the user with which you are doing the `git pull` (a `sudo git pull`, for instance, would use `/root/.ssh` instead of `~You/.ssh`)

Comment: If i use just `git pull` without the `sudo` command does not let me pull, the terminal throws: _error: cannot open '.git/FETCH_HEAD': Permission denied_.

Can you explain me how to do the cd + git that you mencioned in the first step, please?

Comment: @Alfito69420 Thant might be because the repository was initially cloned/created with `sudo`. That means you need to use `sudo`, but also that your key must be in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: i did the same process but to root user: i created the sshkey with rsa from root user and saved it in /root/.ssh and added it with ssh-add in /root/.ssh.id_rsa and when i try to pull the terminal still throwing me this: 

_git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists_.

Comment: @Alfito69420 You need first to check if `sudo ssh -T git@github.com` gives you the welcome message.

Comment: i did it already, the terminal throws the next:

_git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)_

Comment: @Alfito69420 As long as the `sudo ssh -T git@github.com` does not work, the sudo git clone won't either. Check with `sudo ssh -Tv git@github.com` if you see your key used. Try with a key created *without* passphrase (so no `ssh-add` needed)